# GeneXus: How to export properties of Knowledge Base / Version / Generators / Environments with an MSBUILD task?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, genexus

It is easy to export the KB properties to a file with the Genexus IDE.

Is it possible to do the same using MSBUILD tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not fully supported. The [Export](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?3908,MSBuild%20Tasks#Export) MSBuild task lacks the necessary properties to allow stating that KB, version or environment properties should be exported.

There are several [getter properties tasks](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?3908,MSBuild%20Tasks#GetKnowledgeBaseProperty%2C%20GetVersionProperty%2C%20GetEnvironmentProperty%2C%20GetGeneratorProperty%2C%20GetDataStoreProperty%2C%20GetObjectProperty), that allow reading single properties for different elements, although it's cumbersome to use them to export all properties of a given element.

As of build 161356 of the beta channel, it's possible to set the boolean properties `ExportKBProperties`, `ExportVersionProperties` and `ExportEnvironmentProperties` in the Export MSBuild task, in order to export those kind of properties.

Comment: Thanks!. Night Build 161356is not yet available for beta testers.
I'll try it when they publish it.